# Create ellipse using php

Tags: php, image, gd, ellipse

I need to create an ellipse like below with custom colors.

[image: Custom image]

I'm using [Intervention image](http://image.intervention.io/) library to achieve this.

What i've done is :
I've created 6 different transparent images for each section.
And trying to create a canvas and then masking other layer on it but the result is not as expected. 
I'm able to color only the first section of the image through this process.

```
    Image::configure(array('driver' => 'gd'));
    $img = Image::canvas(150,104,'#000')->insert(WWW_ROOT.DS.IMAGES_URL.'test/masks/1.png');
    $img->mask(WWW_ROOT.DS.IMAGES_URL.'test/masks/2.png', true);
    $img->mask(WWW_ROOT.DS.IMAGES_URL.'test/masks/3.png', true);
    $img->mask(WWW_ROOT.DS.IMAGES_URL.'test/masks/4.png', true);
    $img->mask(WWW_ROOT.DS.IMAGES_URL.'test/masks/5.png', true);
    $img->mask(WWW_ROOT.DS.IMAGES_URL.'test/masks/6.png', true);
    $img->save(WWW_ROOT.DS.IMAGES_URL.'test/test.png');
    echo $img->response();
```

I need help to create the above Custom Color image or any other options to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to achieve the desired result.

What i've done is :

Used this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkJ9b.png) to get polygon coordinates of each region through this [jQuery library](https://github.com/fahrenheit-marketing/jquery-canvas-area-draw).

After getting coordinates for each region I created the desired image using [polygon](http://image.intervention.io/api/polygon) function provided by [Intervention Image Library](http://image.intervention.io/).

Thanks to all for your help, maybe this can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but better :

```
<?php
     $image = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);


    $white    = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    $gray     = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0);
    $darkgray = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90);
    $navy     = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80);
    $darknavy = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50);
    $red      = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
    $darkred  = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x90, 0x00, 0x00);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);


    for ($i = 60; $i > 50; $i--) {
       imagefilledarc($image, 150, $i, 300, 50, 0, 60, $darknavy, IMG_ARC_PIE);
       imagefilledarc($image, 150, $i, 300, 50, 60, 120 , $darkgray, IMG_ARC_PIE);
       imagefilledarc($image, 150, $i, 300, 50, 120, 180 , $darkred, IMG_ARC_PIE);

       imagefilledarc($image, 150, $i, 300, 50, 180, 240 , $navy, IMG_ARC_PIE);
       imagefilledarc($image, 150, $i, 300, 50, 240, 270 , $gray, IMG_ARC_PIE);
       imagefilledarc($image, 150, $i, 300, 50, 270, 360 , $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);



    }

    imagefilledarc($image, 150, 50, 300, 50, 0, 60, $navy, IMG_ARC_PIE);
    imagefilledarc($image, 150, 50, 300, 50, 60, 120 , $gray, IMG_ARC_PIE);
    imagefilledarc($image, 150, 50, 300, 50, 120, 180 , $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);

    imagefilledarc($image, 150, 50, 300, 50, 180, 240 , $navy, IMG_ARC_PIE);
    imagefilledarc($image, 150, 50, 300, 50, 240, 270 , $gray, IMG_ARC_PIE);
    imagefilledarc($image, 150, 50, 300, 50, 270, 360 , $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);

    imagefilledarc($image, 150, 50, 280, 40, 0, 360, $white, IMG_ARC_PIE);



    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but its nowhere near the image i provided in question above.

Comment: Still the image is distorted, don't know how to make it crisp but i appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `imageellipse(),` `imagefilledellipse()` and `imagefilledarc()` ?

```
<?php

    // Création de l'image
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

    // Allocation de quelques couleurs
    $white    = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    $gray     = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0);
    $darkgray = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90);
    $navy     = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80);
    $darknavy = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50);
    $red      = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
    $darkred  = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x90, 0x00, 0x00);

    // Création de l'effet 3D
    for ($i = 60; $i > 50; $i--) {
       imagefilledarc($image, 50, $i, 100, 50, 0, 45, $darknavy, IMG_ARC_PIE);
       imagefilledarc($image, 50, $i, 100, 50, 45, 75 , $darkgray, IMG_ARC_PIE);
       imagefilledarc($image, 50, $i, 100, 50, 75, 360 , $darkred, IMG_ARC_PIE);
    }

    imagefilledarc($image, 50, 50, 100, 50, 0, 45, $navy, IMG_ARC_PIE);
    imagefilledarc($image, 50, 50, 100, 50, 45, 75 , $gray, IMG_ARC_PIE);
    imagefilledarc($image, 50, 50, 100, 50, 75, 360 , $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);


    // Affichage de l'image
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
    ?>
```

Comment: I've already seen this example on php.net but the image created is not crisp also how can i give it a feel like the image in question ?

Comment: I dont have the best solution but maybe this could help :