# Round image corners using intervention image and laravel 5.4

Tags: php, image, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, intervention

I need insert some images to another image using intervention image and laravel.

This is my main image:

[image: main image]

And these are my images to insert to main image:

[image: r1 image]

[image: r2 image]

And finally this image after insert:

[image: final image sample]

Well, I use this code to make this:

```
    $img        = Image::make(asset('images/cover.png' ) )->encode('jpg', 15);

    $token      = Session::get('_token');

    $imgWidth   = $img->width();
    $imgHeight  = $img->height();

    $coverImages = Storage::allFiles('public/' . $token . '/cover');

    $r1 = Image::make(asset('storage/' . $token . '/cover/r1.png') );
    $r2 = Image::make(asset('storage/' . $token . '/cover/r2.png') );

    $r1->resize(80, 180, function ($constraint){
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });

    $r2->resize(80, 180, function ($constraint){
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });

    $img->insert($r1, 'top-left', 190, 175);
    $img->insert($r2, 'top-left', 290, 175);

    $img->save( public_path("storage/{$token}/111111.png"));
```

Now I need to round **`r1.png`** and **`r2.png`** corners to fit `main image`.

Do you know how can I do this?

***Thanks in Advance***

***NOTE :***

Thanks to `@Pascal Meunier`, but

> I need to round `r1.png` corners by itself, because I have to save rounded image in another place again for some reasons...

Comment: i think This can help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094341/php-gd-how-to-circular-crop-3-square-images-and-merge-into-1-image-maintaining-t

Comment: @DCoder Thanks for your comment but I prefer do this using `intervention` class not using `GD`

Comment: Did you try to use circle function .check this [link](http://image.intervention.io/api/circle)

Answer (score 6):

I found a way, by using a `canvas` and inserting `r1` and `r2` before the `main` image.

```
$cover = Image::make('main.png');
$r1 = Image::make('r1.png');
$r2 = Image::make('r2.png');

$r1->resize(80, 180, function ($constraint){
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

$r2->resize(80, 180, function ($constraint){
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

$canvas = Image::canvas(746, 738);

$canvas->insert($r1, 'top-left', 190, 175);
$canvas->insert($r2, 'top-left', 290, 175);
$canvas->insert($cover);

$canvas->save('final.png');
```

The result looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer... It's good trick but I need to round `r1.png` by iteself... Is there a way to do this???

Comment: please check out my question again... I did add a note to this

Answer (score 2):

I have not try this myself, but it could be done using [`mask` method](http://image.intervention.io/api/mask) from the `Intervention` class. With this you would need another image of a white rounded rectangle with a black background for the mask.

it should work like this:

```
$img        = Image::make(asset('images/cover.png' ) )->encode('jpg', 15);

$token      = Session::get('_token');

$imgWidth   = $img->width();
$imgHeight  = $img->height();

$coverImages = Storage::allFiles('public/' . $token . '/cover');

$r1 = Image::make(asset('storage/' . $token . '/cover/r1.png') );
$r2 = Image::make(asset('storage/' . $token . '/cover/r2.png') );

$r1->resize(80, 180, function ($constraint){
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->mask('public/mask.png');

$r2->resize(80, 180, function ($constraint){
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->mask('public/mask.png');

$img->insert($r1, 'top-left', 190, 175);
$img->insert($r2, 'top-left', 290, 175);

$img->save( public_path("storage/{$token}/111111.png"));
```